# Cómo hacer un diagrama de Taylor

Tags: python, base-de-datos

quisiera realizar un Diagrama de Taylor en Python. No sé cómo debería realizarlo, ni por donde empezar. Si alguien me puede dar una mano se los agradecería mucho.
Saludos,
Florencia.

Comment: Hola Florencia, lo de "Diagrama de Taylor en Python" es un poco amplio.... Si hablamos de Matplotlib hay que crearlo "manualmente" o puedes usar librerías que ayuden en la tarea, como [SkillMetrics](https://pypi.org/project/SkillMetrics/) o algunas muy especializadas como [vacumm] o [verif](https://pypi.org/project/verif/) que también ofrecen esta funcionalidad (http://www.ifremer.fr/vacumm/index.html).

Comment: Aquí tienes un muy buen ejemplo usando Matplotlib mediante ejes flotantes https://gist.github.com/ycopin/3342888 que es un buen punto de partida.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla !